# How can I use T4MVC with the external login confirmation form in the default MVC5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, t4mvc

In the default ASP.NET MVC 5 web project, the "Login" view ("Login.cshtml") has a `BeginForm` call like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

I'm trying to convert all my `ActionLink`, `BeginForm` (etc.) calls to use T4MVC, and so I changed it to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.Login().AddRouteValue("ReturnUrl", (string)ViewBag.ReturnUrl), FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

...which worked fine.

However, there's another form in "ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml", which starts like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

I tried to use the same approach:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Account.ExternalLoginConfirmation().AddRouteValue(...)
```

...but the object returned by `MVC.Account.ExternalLoginConfirmation` has no `AddRouteValue` method.

I think this is because `ExternalLoginConfirmation` is an async action method that actually returns a `Task<T>` rather than just a `T`.

Is there any way I can get this to work with T4MVC, or do I simply need to leave this one alone? (I know I can just replace the magic strings using `MVC.Account.ActionNames.ExternalLoginConfirmation` and `MVC.Account.Name`), but it would be nice to be able to use the helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [this thread](https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/discussions/450588). Basically, try:

```
MVC.Account.ExternalLoginConfirmation().Result.AddRouteValue(...)
```

Comment: Yikes. That **so** looks like it would execute the Task, but if not then great - thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, it won't. Not anymore than in what you had above is the actual function called. Every call you make in the T4MVC world is fake :)